# Preemptively getting pages with HTML5 offline manifest or just their data

Tags: html, offline, offlineapps

### Background

I have a (glorified) CRUD application that I'd like to enable HTML5 offline support with. The cache-manifest system looks simple yet powerful, but I'm curious about how I can allow users to access data while offline.

For example, suppose I have these pages for the entity "Case" (i.e. this is CRM case-management software):

```
http://myapplication.com/Case
http://myapplication.com/Case/{id}
http://myapplication.com/Case/Create
```

The first URI contains a paged listing of all cases, using the querystring parameters `pageIndex` and `pageSize`, e.g. `/Case?pageIndex=2&pageSize=20`.

The second URI is the template for editing individual cases, e.g. `/Case/1` or `/Case/56`.

Finally, `/Case/Create` is the form used to create cases.

### The Problem

I would like all three to be available offline.

#### /Case

The simple way would be to add `/Case` to the cache-manifest, however that would break paging (as the links wouldn't work).

I think I could instead add something like `/Case/AllData` which is an XML resource, which is cached and if offline then a script on `/Case` would use this XML data to populate the list and provide for pagination.

If I go for the latter, how can I have this XML data stored in the in-browser SQL database instead of as a cached resource? I think using the SQL database would be more resilient.

#### /Case/{id}

This is more complicated. There is the simple solution of manually adding `/Case/1`, `/Case/2`, `/Case/3` etc... to `/Case/1234`, but there can be hundreds or even thousands of cases so this isn't very practical.

I think the system should provide access to the 30 most recent cases, for example. As above, how can I store this data in the database?

Also, how would this work? If I don't explicitly add `/Case/34` to the manifest and the user clicks on to `/Case/34` how can I get the browser to load a page that my JavaScript will populate based on the browser's SQL database data and not display the offline message?

#### /Case/Create

This one is more simple - as it's just an empty page and on the `<form>`'s `submit` action my script would detect if it's offline, and if it is offline then it would add it to the browser's SQL database. Does this sound okay?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be looking at a LocalStorage database (though it does have some downsides), but there are other alternatives such as WebSQL and IndexedDB.

Also I don't think you should be using numeric Id's if you are allowing people to create as you will get Primary Key conflicts, it is probably best to use something like a GUID.

Another thing you need is the ability to push those new cases onto the server. there could be multiple...

Can they be edited? If they can I think you really need to be thinking about synchronization and conflict resolution hard very hard if that is the case.

Shameless self promotion, I have a project that is designed to handle these very issues, though it's not done, it's close. You can see it (with an ugly but very functional) demo at https://github.com/forbesmyester/SyncIt